# Should I consider memmove() O(n) or O(1)?

Tags: c, complexity-theory, standard-library

this may be a silly question, but I want to calculate the complexity of one of my algorithms, and I am not sure what complexity to consider for the [memmove()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memmove/) function.

Can you please help / explain ?

```
void * memmove ( void * destination, const void * source, size_t num );
```

So is the complexity O(num) or O(1). I suppose it's O(num), but I am not sure as I lack for now the understanding of what's going on under the hood.

Comment: The correct answer is probably that it is implementation dependent. You can imagine an unusual system where memory is really some complex graph or linked list. In every real system I'm aware of it is proportional to num.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the running time of `memmove` increases in direct proportionality with the number of bytes it is required to move, it is O(n).

Comment: O(n) is the correct asymptotic complexity, but I don't think I would use the term "direct proportionality" in this context, even for something as simple as `memmove`.  Consider n=4 vs. n=1 bytes on a 32-bit architecture: the n=1 case might actually be the more expensive operation!

Comment: It's `O(n)` where `n` is the count passed to `memmove()` - but that might not be proportional to the `n` that you're using to characterise your algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

What are you applying the `memmove()` operation to - selected elements in the algorithm or all of them? Are you applying `memmove()` to elements more than once?

Those are the things that will matter to the algorithm's complexity.

That answer may be different that the complexity of `memmove()` itself regarding the arrays of `char` elements that  `memmove()` deals with (for which `memmove()` is an O(n) operation).