# What is the Big O Complexity of Reversing the Order of Columns in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, numpy, big-o

So lets say I have a DataFrame in pandas with a m rows and n columns. Let's also say that I wanted to reverse the order of the columns, which can be done with the following code:

```
df_reversed = df[df.columns[::-1]]
```

What is the Big O complexity of this operation? I'm assuming this would depend on the number of columns, but would it also depend on the number of rows?

Comment: Note to self: go for the lowest orders of magnitude when setting up such tests :) crashed the laptop.

Comment: If you are going for performance, go with slicing `df.iloc[:,::-1]`, which returns a view and hence should be virtually free as opposed to `df[df.columns[::-1]]` that creates a copy as you are indexing in the latter one.

Comment: @Divakar, As a general rule, is this true of only `iloc`, or does `loc` also return views? Probably beyond the scope of a single comment, but I'm also interested in *why* direct indexing via `df[col_list]` should return a copy (is it a design choice / side-effect / is there any benefit?).

Comment: @divakar if I return a view, can I still do operations on this and then once again reverse the order of the columns and end up with the original dataframe with the operations applied?

Comment: @TimHoldsworth Once you do operations, you create a copy.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know how Pandas implements this, but I did test it empirically. I ran the following code (in a Jupyter notebook) to test the speed of the operation:

```
def get_dummy_df(n):
    return pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2]*n, 'b': [4,5]*n, 'c': [7,8]*n})

df = get_dummy_df(100)
print df.shape
%timeit df_r = df[df.columns[::-1]]

df = get_dummy_df(1000)
print df.shape
%timeit df_r = df[df.columns[::-1]]

df = get_dummy_df(10000)
print df.shape
%timeit df_r = df[df.columns[::-1]]

df = get_dummy_df(100000)
print df.shape
%timeit df_r = df[df.columns[::-1]]

df = get_dummy_df(1000000)
print df.shape
%timeit df_r = df[df.columns[::-1]]

df = get_dummy_df(10000000)
print df.shape
%timeit df_r = df[df.columns[::-1]]
```

The output was:

```
(200, 3)
1000 loops, best of 3: 419 µs per loop
(2000, 3)
1000 loops, best of 3: 425 µs per loop
(20000, 3)
1000 loops, best of 3: 498 µs per loop
(200000, 3)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.66 ms per loop
(2000000, 3)
10 loops, best of 3: 25.2 ms per loop
(20000000, 3)
1 loop, best of 3: 207 ms per loop
```

As you can see, in the first 3 cases, the overhead of the operation is what takes most of the time (400-500µs), but from the 4th case, the time it takes starts to be proportional to the amount of data, increasing in an order of magnitude each time.

So, assuming there must also be a proportion to *n*, it seems that we are dealing with O(m*n)

Answer (score 4):

The Big O complexity (as of Pandas 0.24) is `m*n` where `m` is the number of columns and `n` is the number of rows. Note, this is when using the `DataFrame.__getitem__` method (aka `[]`) with an `Index` ([see relevant code, with other types that would trigger a copy](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/core/frame.py#L2680)).

Here is a helpful stack trace:

```
 <ipython-input-4-3162cae03863>(2)<module>()
      1 columns = df.columns[::-1]
----> 2 df_reversed = df[columns]

  pandas/core/frame.py(2682)__getitem__()
   2681             # either boolean or fancy integer index
-> 2682             return self._getitem_array(key)
   2683         elif isinstance(key, DataFrame):

  pandas/core/frame.py(2727)_getitem_array()
   2726             indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
-> 2727             return self._take(indexer, axis=1)
   2728 

  pandas/core/generic.py(2789)_take()
   2788                                    axis=self._get_block_manager_axis(axis),
-> 2789                                    verify=True)
   2790         result = self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self)

  pandas/core/internals.py(4539)take()
   4538         return self.reindex_indexer(new_axis=new_labels, indexer=indexer,
-> 4539                                     axis=axis, allow_dups=True)
   4540 

  pandas/core/internals.py(4421)reindex_indexer()
   4420             new_blocks = self._slice_take_blocks_ax0(indexer,
-> 4421                                                      fill_tuple=(fill_value,))
   4422         else:

  pandas/core/internals.py(1254)take_nd()
   1253             new_values = algos.take_nd(values, indexer, axis=axis,
-> 1254                                        allow_fill=False)
   1255         else:

> pandas/core/algorithms.py(1658)take_nd()
   1657     import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
-> 1658     func = _get_take_nd_function(arr.ndim, arr.dtype, out.dtype, axis=axis,
   1659                                  mask_info=mask_info)
   1660     func(arr, indexer, out, fill_value)
```

The `func` call on L1660 in `pandas/core/algorithms` ultimately calls a  cython function with `O(m * n)` complexity. This is where data from the the original data is copied into `out`. `out` contains a copy of the original data in reversed order.

```
    inner_take_2d_axis0_template = """\
    cdef:
        Py_ssize_t i, j, k, n, idx
        %(c_type_out)s fv

    n = len(indexer)
    k = values.shape[1]

    fv = fill_value

    IF %(can_copy)s:
        cdef:
            %(c_type_out)s *v
            %(c_type_out)s *o

        #GH3130
        if (values.strides[1] == out.strides[1] and
            values.strides[1] == sizeof(%(c_type_out)s) and
            sizeof(%(c_type_out)s) * n >= 256):

            for i from 0 <= i < n:
                idx = indexer[i]
                if idx == -1:
                    for j from 0 <= j < k:
                        out[i, j] = fv
                else:
                    v = &values[idx, 0]
                    o = &out[i, 0]
                    memmove(o, v, <size_t>(sizeof(%(c_type_out)s) * k))
            return

    for i from 0 <= i < n:
        idx = indexer[i]
        if idx == -1:
            for j from 0 <= j < k:
                out[i, j] = fv
        else:
            for j from 0 <= j < k:
                out[i, j] = %(preval)svalues[idx, j]%(postval)s
"""
```

Note that in the above template function, there is a path that uses `memmove` (which is the path taken in this case because we are mapping from `int64` to `int64` and the dimension of the output is identical as we are just switching the indexes). Note that [`memmove` is still O(n)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710002/should-i-consider-memmove-on-or-o1), being proportional to the number of bytes it has to copy, although likely faster than writing to the indexes directly.

Comment: I went ahead and added some more examples which show more context into the path taken after calling `__getitem__` and the cython function called, which ultimately is where most of the time is spent for large values. The logic in `__getitem__` is not always intuitive, but I found this GH issue to be helpful for explaining what different inputs do under the hood https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/9595.

Comment: Thank you, this goes a long way to explaining the behaviour we see.

Answer (score -1):

I ran an empirical test using `big_O` fitting library [here](https://github.com/pberkes/big_O)

> **Note**: All tests have been conducted on independent variable sweeping 6 orders of magnitude (**i.e.**
>
> - `rows` from `10` to `10^6` vs. constant `column` size of `3`,
> - `columns` from `10` to `10^6` vs. constant `row` size of `10`

The result shows that the `columns` reverse operation `.columns[::-1]` complexity in the `DataFrame` is

1. **Cubical**: `O(n^3)` where n is the number of `rows`
2. **Cubical**: `O(n^3)` where n is the number of `columns`

> **Prerequisites**: You will need to install `big_o()` using terminal command `pip install big_o`

**Code**

```
import big_o
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

SWEAP_LOG10 = 6
COLUMNS = 3
ROWS = 10

def build_df(rows, columns):
    # To isolated the creation of the DataFrame from the inversion operation.
    narray = np.zeros(rows*columns).reshape(rows, columns)
    df = pd.DataFrame(narray)
    return df

def flip_columns(df):
    return df[df.columns[::-1]]

def get_row_df(n, m=COLUMNS):
    return build_df(1*10**n, m)

def get_column_df(n, m=ROWS):
    return build_df(m, 1*10**n)


# infer the big_o on columns[::-1] operation vs. rows
best, others = big_o.big_o(flip_columns, get_row_df, min_n=1, max_n=SWEAP_LOG10,n_measures=SWEAP_LOG10, n_repeats=10)

# print results
print('Measuring .columns[::-1] complexity against rapid increase in # rows')
print('-'*80 + '\nBig O() fits: {}\n'.format(best) + '-'*80)

for class_, residual in others.items():
    print('{:<60s}  (res: {:.2G})'.format(str(class_), residual))

print('-'*80)

# infer the big_o on columns[::-1] operation vs. columns
best, others = big_o.big_o(flip_columns, get_column_df, min_n=1, max_n=SWEAP_LOG10,n_measures=SWEAP_LOG10, n_repeats=10)

# print results
print()
print('Measuring .columns[::-1] complexity against rapid increase in # columns')
print('-'*80 + '\nBig O() fits: {}\n'.format(best) + '-'*80)

for class_, residual in others.items():
    print('{:<60s}  (res: {:.2G})'.format(str(class_), residual))
    
print('-'*80)
```

**Results**

```
Measuring .columns[::-1] complexity against rapid increase in # rows
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Big O() fits: Cubic: time = -0.017 + 0.00067*n^3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Constant: time = 0.032                                        (res: 0.021)
Linear: time = -0.051 + 0.024*n                               (res: 0.011)
Quadratic: time = -0.026 + 0.0038*n^2                         (res: 0.0077)
Cubic: time = -0.017 + 0.00067*n^3                            (res: 0.0052)
Polynomial: time = -6.3 * x^1.5                               (res: 6)
Logarithmic: time = -0.026 + 0.053*log(n)                     (res: 0.015)
Linearithmic: time = -0.024 + 0.012*n*log(n)                  (res: 0.0094)
Exponential: time = -7 * 0.66^n                               (res: 3.6)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------


Measuring .columns[::-1] complexity against rapid increase in # columns
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Big O() fits: Cubic: time = -0.28 + 0.009*n^3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Constant: time = 0.38                                         (res: 3.9)
Linear: time = -0.73 + 0.32*n                                 (res: 2.1)
Quadratic: time = -0.4 + 0.052*n^2                            (res: 1.5)
Cubic: time = -0.28 + 0.009*n^3                               (res: 1.1)
Polynomial: time = -6 * x^2.2                                 (res: 16)
Logarithmic: time = -0.39 + 0.71*log(n)                       (res: 2.8)
Linearithmic: time = -0.38 + 0.16*n*log(n)                    (res: 1.8)
Exponential: time = -7 * 1^n                                  (res: 9.7)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You're neglecting overhead at small orders of magnitude

Comment: And yes, technically if it's O(n), O(n^3) applies too, but it's not very useful.

Comment: @MadPhysicist can you elaborate on **overhead on small orders of magnitude**

Comment: The other answer does a great job of that.

Comment: `O(n)` is **linear** i.e. list search, `O(n^c)` is **polynomial** i.e. nested loops and recursive loops. they are two different things.

Comment: Your just doing a fit to a limited number of points, and the low tail is throwing you off. The other answer is actually looking at the big O. I seriously doubt that any basic operation in pandas is O(n^3)

Comment: Big O needs to look into worst-case scenarios, but I think you have a point. I'll reconfigure the test parameters & see if it come with a different answer.