# How to move a column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, indexing

I want to take a column indexed 'length' and make it my second column. It currently exists as the 5th column. I have tried:

```
colnames = big_df.columns.tolist()

# make index "length" the second column in the big_df
colnames = colnames[0] + colnames[4] + colnames[:-1] 

big_df = big_df[colnames]
```

I see the following error:

> TypeError: must be str, not list

I'm not sure how to interpret this error because it actually should be a `list`, right?

Also, is there a general method to move any column by label to a specified position? My columns only have one level, i.e. no `MultiIndex` involved.

Comment: More generally, what is best practice for moving columns to organize a dataframe?

Comment: I would strongly recommend you use `df.columns = colnames` instead of `df[[colnames]]` as `__getitem__` [triggers a copy operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51700776/9209546). But this is the trivial bit. I haven't seen any good NumPy-based solution for the reordering aspect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Correcting your error

> I'm not sure how to interpret this error because it actually should be
> a list, right?

No: `colnames[0]` and `colnames[4]` are scalars, not lists. You can't concatenate a scalar with a list. To make them lists, use square brackets:

```
colnames = [colnames[0]] + [colnames[4]] + colnames[:-1]
```

You can either use `df[[colnames]]` or `df.reindex(columns=colnames)`: both [necessarily trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56462088/why-doesnt-pandas-reindex-operate-in-place) a copy operation as this transformation cannot be processed in place.

#### Generic solution

But converting arrays to lists and then concatenating lists manually is not only expensive, but prone to error. A [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13148429/how-to-change-the-order-of-dataframe-columns) has many list-based solutions, but a NumPy-based solution is worthwhile since `pd.Index` objects are stored as NumPy arrays.

The key here is to modify the NumPy array via slicing rather than concatenation. There are only 2 cases to handle: when the desired position exists after the current position, and vice versa.

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from string import ascii_uppercase

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(ascii_uppercase))

def shifter(df, col_to_shift, pos_to_move):
    arr = df.columns.values
    idx = df.columns.get_loc(col_to_shift)
    if idx == pos_to_move:
        pass
    elif idx > pos_to_move:
        arr[pos_to_move+1: idx+1] = arr[pos_to_move: idx]
    else:
        arr[idx: pos_to_move] = arr[idx+1: pos_to_move+1]
    arr[pos_to_move] = col_to_shift
    df = df.reindex(columns=arr)
    return df
    
df = df.pipe(shifter, 'J', 1)

print(df.columns)

Index(['A', 'J', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N',
       'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'],
      dtype='object')
```

#### Performance benchmarking

Using NumPy slicing is more efficient with a large number of columns versus a list-based method:

```
n = 10000
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=list(range(n)))

def shifter2(df, col_to_shift, pos_to_move):
    cols = df.columns.tolist()
    cols.insert(pos_to_move, cols.pop(df.columns.get_loc(col_to_shift)))
    df = df.reindex(columns=cols)
    return df

%timeit df.pipe(shifter, 590, 5)   # 381 µs
%timeit df.pipe(shifter2, 590, 5)  # 1.92 ms
```