# Pandas, loc vs non loc for boolean indexing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, where-clause

All the research I do point to using `loc` as the way to filter a dataframe by a col(s) value(s), today I was reading [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html) and I discovered by the examples I tested, that `loc` isn't really needed when filtering cols by it's values:

EX:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0, 20, 0.5).reshape(8, 5), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])    

df.loc[df['a'] >= 15]

      a     b     c     d     e
6  15.0  15.5  16.0  16.5  17.0
7  17.5  18.0  18.5  19.0  19.5

df[df['a'] >= 15]

      a     b     c     d     e
6  15.0  15.5  16.0  16.5  17.0
7  17.5  18.0  18.5  19.0  19.5
```

**Note: I do know that doing `loc` or `iloc` return the rows by it's index and the position. I'm not comparing based on this functionality.**

But when filtering, doing "`where`" clauses what's the difference between using or not using `loc`? If any. And why do all the examples I come across regarding this subject use `loc`?

Comment: In this case, you're right.  For simple filtering there is no difference between passing your boolean array as `df.loc[]` or directly to `df[]`.  The power or `.loc[]` comes from more complex look-ups, when you want specific rows and columns.  It's syntax is also more flexible, generalized, and less error-prone than chaining together multiple boolean conditions.  Overall it makes for more robust accessing/filtering of data in your df.

Comment: @cvonsteg, As an extension, would you say `df[df.columns[::-1]]` would be the same (i.e. just syntactic sugar or O(1) performance differential) as `df.iloc[:, ::-1]`? Because that [doesn't seem to be the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51486063/what-is-the-big-o-complexity-of-reversing-the-order-of-columns-in-pandas-datafra). Personally, I find it confusing there doesn't seem to be any official docs on what `__getitem__` does and when/how.

Comment: @jpp full disclaimer - I have not looked into this, so the following is just speculation. For large data sets, I imagine you may see divergence between the two approaches, favoring .iloc[]. This is solely based on the notion that df[df.columns[]] performs multiple operations on the df (creating Index object, then `__getitem__`) whilst .iloc[] is probably an optimized approach to this (maybe invoking generators, something along those lines?). But you're right the [Data Model](http://farmdev.com/src/secrets/magicmethod/index.html#introducing-getitem) docs are pretty sparse.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As per the docs, [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) accepts a boolean array for selecting rows, and in your case

```
>>> df['a'] >= 15
>>> 
0    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
4    False
5    False
6     True
7     True
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

is treated as a boolean array.

The fact that you can omit `loc` here and issue `df[df['a'] >= 15]` is a special case convenience according to Wes McKinney, the author of `pandas`.

Quoting directly from his book, [Python for Data Analysis](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/python-for-data/9781491957653/), p. 144, `df[val]` is used to...

> Select single column or sequence of columns from the DataFrame; **special case
>   conveniences: boolean array (filter rows)**, slice (slice rows), or boolean DataFrame
>   (set values based on some criterion)

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.__getitem__` and `pd.Series.__getitem__` don't seem to be documented for Boolean indexing. Of course, many cases of `df[col_name]` exist in the docs. So possibly we shouldn't even rely on row-wise indexing and always use `loc`?

Comment: @jpp It would probably be a bit more explicit to use `loc`. Personally, I would like to stick to the convenience feature. I doubt the devs will take it away at this point.

Comment: I take your point. But I would also say performance is *not* always identical in the general case. As an example `df[df.columns[::-1]]` can perform much worse than `df.iloc[:, ::-1]`. I wish there was more advice on `__getitem__` as it is (as you indicate) pretty fundamental to how people use Pandas.