# Pandas Dataframe - Using Comparison Operator (==) vs idxmin() is producing different results

Tags: python, pandas

This is related to one of the questions that was trying to respond to. Id: [61801654](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61801654/pandas-get-value-based-on-minimum-value-in-other-column/61801708#61801746)

Dataset:

```
Q   GDP
2008q3  14891.6 
2008q4  14577.0 
2009q1  14375.0 
2009q2  14355.6
```

The idea was to get the value of Q for minm value of GDP.
The correct answer was:

```
df.loc[df['GDP'].idxmin()]['Q']
```

Output:

```
2009q2
<class 'str'>
```

What I thought could also be the answer is this:

```
df.loc[df['GDP'] == df['GDP'].min()]['Q']
```

However, the output with this is:

```
3    2009q2
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

For reference, 3 is the index of the dataframe that I created using the read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+') function:

```
df = pd.read_clipboard(sep='\s\s+')

        Q      GDP
0  2008q3  14891.6
1  2008q4  14577.0
2  2009q1  14375.0
3  2009q2  14355.6
```

I want to understand why is `df.loc[df['GDP'] == df['GDP'].min()]['Q']` returning a series while `df.loc[df['GDP'].idxmin()]['Q']` is just returning a string value.

Could not find a similar problem already been answered. My apologies if its a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Scenario 1

`df['GDP'] == df['GDP'].min()` gives you a boolean series.

```
>>> mask = df['GDP'] == df['GDP'].min()
>>> mask
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
Name: GDP, dtype: bool
```

Indexing into a dataframe with a boolean series ([with or without the `loc` accessor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53297140/pandas-loc-vs-non-loc-for-boolean-indexing)) gives you a dataframe.

```
>>> df_filtered = df.loc[mask]
>>> type(result1)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
>>> df_filtered
        Q      GDP
3  2009q2  14355.6
```

Selecting a column from a dataframe gives you a series.

```
>>> type(df_filtered['Q'])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> df_filtered['Q']
3    2009q2
Name: Q, dtype: object
```

#### Scenario 2

`df['GDP'].idxmin()` gives you a single value.

```
>>> idxmin = df['GDP'].idxmin()
>>> idxmin
3
```

Selecting a single row of a dataframe returns a series.

```
>>> row = df.loc[idxmin]
>>> type(row)
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
>>> row
Q       2009q2
GDP    14355.6
Name: 3, dtype: object
```

Indexing into a series gives you a single value (if the index is unique).

```
>>> row['Q']
'2009q2'
```